# chrome.hid API with composite device

Tags: google-chrome-app, hid

The chrome.hid.getDevices call does not enumerate the HID interface for a composite device. Using the hid sample app https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/hid, I can see a usb mouse and connect to it, but I can not find the HID interface on a composite device (HID + audio) plugged in.  The chrome.usb.getDevices call does find it, but even then I can't claim the HID interface manually.  Is this something that should work?  How to debug?  The specific HID interface is Class:3, SubClass:0, Protocol:0 (not a keyboard, which is Protocol: 1, so shouldn't be blacklisted because of that)

Judging by /var/log/message and ls -l /dev/hidraw*, I see that the regular mouse has it's group changed to dev-broker, but the group for my composite device stays as root.  The message in the logs say "DenyClaimedHidrawDeviceRule: DENY" indicating that perhaps another kernel driver is owning my hid interface, or usb audio is owning the entire device?  This thread [here at chromium.org](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-os-dev/c7JDZG-T_gc) seems to be the issue I am seeing, but doesn't mention any work-around/fix.  Normally I'd add a udev rule, or blacklist the driver, or even use sys/bus/usb///unbind foo, but none of that works on a chromebook platform which is what I need to run this on.

Comment: The permission broker shouldn't be blocking access to the hidraw device just because the usb audio driver is loaded against another interface on the composite device. This is likely a bug. I need to get my hands on a device matching this description to diagnose it further. What model device are you using?

Comment: Still an issue. The permissions broker is blocking access because one of the subsystem drivers is not hid/usb (it's audio).  How can I send a device to you?

Comment: Send me an Amazon link and I'll buy one (or something similar) for myself.